# How to compare two different tables' columns and matched columns fetch all rows from table one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I am comparing two tables single columns and matched columns fetch all rows

```
select *
from t_registered_std_info
where t_registered_std_info.t_ds_name == attendance.std_name
```

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or SQlite?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (i.e. no images.)

Comment: Considering the OP is using `==` I *suspect* the latter @jarlh, as `==` isn't valid T-SQL. (but then I've no idea if `==` is allowed in SQLite)

Comment: @Larnu, I know, but is it valid SQLite syntax?

Comment: No idea, I was just editing my comment to mention that. But if it is, one would have expected the OP to let us know that were getting an error with that statement. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want do `IN` the other table:

```
select *
from t_registered_std_info
where t_registered_std_info.t_ds_name IN (select attendance.std_name from attendance)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing joining for the table attendance and also a additional = sign in where part.

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_registered_std_info 
INNER JOIN attendance 
    ON -- Please define the relation
WHERE t_registered_std_info.t_ds_name = attendance.std_name
```

Comment: I think the `t_registered_std_info.t_ds_name = attendance.std_name` is the `ON` clause they want.

Comment: Yup.. probably.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all rows from "table1" with matching values from "table2", then use `left join`:

```
select *   -- you should list the columns you want here
from t_registered_std_info rsi left join
     attendance a
     on rsi.t_ds_name = rsi.std_name
```

Notes:

- All table references need to be in a `from` clause in a `select` query.  You cannot "just" refer to a table anywhere.
- The SQL operator for equality is `=`, not `==`, although some databases do recognize the latter.
- When combining multiple tables in the `from` clause, use explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- If you only want columns from one of the tables, then an alternative such as `exists` or `in` might be appropriate.

Comment: I'd say the opposite. Use `INNER JOIN` here.

Comment: @jarlh . . . The title of the question includes "fetch all rows from table one".